# How to use Tailwind CSS with Next.js Image

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I am trying to use Tailwind CSS in an Next.js project but I cant't use my Tailwind classes with Next.js Image component.

Here's my code:

```
<Image
    src={img.img}
    alt="Picture of the author"
    width="200"
    height="200"
    className="bg-mint text-mint fill-current"
></Image>
```

I want to use Tailwind classes instead of the `height` and `width` property of the Next.js Image. But I can't because it throws me an error. Also, `unsized` property throws another error saying it's deprecated. Is there any solution?

Here is the error if I don't use the `height` and `width` property.
[image]

When I use the `layout='fill'` property it shows only one picture. And if I use the `unsized` property, then the following error is shown.

[image]

Comment: Share with us the error output.

Comment: @JuanMarco updated...

Answer (score 104, accepted):

There’s a [discussion and related example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18739#discussioncomment-130777) over at the Next.js GitHub project. It sounds like that example achieves what you want to do. tl;dr:

```js
<div className="h-64 w-96 relative"> // "relative" is required; adjust sizes to your liking
  <Image
    src={img.img}
    alt="Picture of the author"
    layout="fill" // required
    objectFit="cover" // change to suit your needs
    className="rounded-full" // just an example
  />
</div>
```

The image will preserve its original aspect ratio and fill / cover (or whatever `object-fit` you chose) the size of the outer `div`, which you can set using Tailwind classes. Other styles, like rounded corner, can be applied to the `Image`.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the height by the content in it instead of the height of the image?

Comment: @thiras I ended up using `aspect-[]` for that.

Comment: Nextjs switched up their api in Next13, `objectFit` now has to be provided as a style https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#version-history:~:text=%2C-,objectFit,-%2C

Answer (score 5):

It's been solved, no more need for hacky solutions. Just style them using tailwind directly!

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-2

Answer (score 3):

When I read through the Next.js 13 documentation I found out that it is very important to understand that when you are using fill with nextjs Image tag, the parent container should be relative.

```
fill

fill={true} // {true} | {false}
```

A boolean that causes the image to fill the parent element instead of setting width and height.

The parent element must assign position: "relative", position: "fixed", or position: "absolute" style.

By default, the img element will automatically be assigned the position: "absolute" style.

The default image fit behavior will stretch the image to fit the container. You may prefer to set object-fit: "contain" for an image which is letterboxed to fit the container and preserve aspect ratio.

Alternatively, object-fit: "cover" will cause the image to fill the entire container and be cropped to preserve aspect ratio. For this to look correct, the overflow: "hidden" style should be assigned to the parent element.

For more information, see also:

```
position
object-fit
object-position
```

So I did it like this:

```
<div className="relative w-full h-full overflow-hidden">
  <Image   
                                                        
      className="rounded-sm"  
      object-fit="cover" 
      fill={true}  
      alt={group?.name ? group.name : "no details" }
      src="https://www.oddcircles.com/images/group-image.png" 
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fill` property.

`Next.js 14.1.0` example:

```
<Link
    href="/"
    className="relative h-4 w-36 sm:h-5 sm:w-48"
>
    <Image
        src="/logo.svg"
        alt="logo"
        priority={true}
        fill={true}
    />
</Link>
```

From the official documentation:

`fill={true}`

A boolean that causes the image to fill the parent element, which is useful when the width and height are unknown.

The parent element must assign `position: "relative"`, `position: "fixed"`, or `position: "absolute"` style.

By default, the img element will automatically be assigned the `position: "absolute"` style.

**Official documentation:** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#props

Answer (score -1):

You can use a div container and apply a class to it.

```
<div className="bg-mint text-mint fill-current">
    <Image
        src={img.img}
        alt="Picture of the author"
        width="200"
        height="200">
    </Image>
</div>
```