# TailwindCSS + Next.js Image take full height with fill layout

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I'm trying to use the Next.js' `<Image>` component with the `layout=fill` option. Therefore I've created a `relative` `div` that contains the `Image` tag. But I'd like to determine the height by the Image height.

Found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65134645/4132845) but height is statically given there. So I've tried this based on the example.

```
<div className="relative w-full h-full">
  <Image
    src={post.coverImage.url}
    layout="fill"
    alt={post.title}
  />
</div>
```

I've also tried `h-full` or `max-h-full` classes instead of `h-` tags but couldn't succeed.

How can I make its height automatically determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and figured it out after inspecting the element. The problem is how `Image` component takes place in DOM.

[image]

This the Image component on DOM, look there are 2 divs and inside "img" is placed. So you have to target the outer div that wraps `img`.

```
// I add img-wrapper class
<div className="relative w-full h-full   img-wrapper">
  <Image
    src={post.coverImage.url}
    layout="responsive"
    alt={post.title}
  />
</div>
```

and in css:

```
// targeting the first div
.img-wrapper > div {
 // this will take full-height, u can adjust it
  height: 100%;
}
```